# JAX-RS API endpoint returning filename without spanish characters

Tags: java, file, character-encoding, jax-rs

I have the following endpoint declared in Java (File download)

```
@GET
@Path("/download")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM+";charset=UTF-8")
public Response downloadFileWithGet(@QueryParam("IdFile") String idFile
                                    ) throws IOException {
        
    
    try {
        FileCloudStream controllerResponse = ArchivosController.descargarArchivo(Integer.parseInt(idFile));
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok( (Object) controllerResponse.getStream());
        System.out.println("Filename without encode: " + controllerResponse.getArchivoOracle().getArchivo().getNombreArchivo());
        System.out.println("FileName with encode " + ArchivoOracleModel.encodeDefaultISO(controllerResponse.getArchivoOracle().getArchivo().getNombreArchivo()));
        response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" +controllerResponse.getArchivoOracle().getArchivo().getNombreArchivo() );
        return response.build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(500).entity("No se puede descargar el archivo.").build();
    }
        
    
}
```

the encode method:

```
public static String encodeDefaultISO(String input) {
        return new String (input.getBytes (StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

where

```
controllerResponse.getArchivoOracle().getArchivo().getNombreArchivo()) //gets the filename from DB
OUTPUT: pruebá año 2021.xlsx // This is the correct filename
```

and

```
ArchivoOracleModel.encodeDefaultISO(controllerResponse.getArchivoOracle().getArchivo().getNombreArchivo())) //gets the filename from db then encode
OUTPUT: prueb� a�o 2021.xlsx
```

When im trying to download the file from any browser i get this filename: prueb a o 2021.xlsx

i have tried both ways of getting the filename in the Content-Disposition and both returns: prueb a o 2021.xlsx

```
response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" +controllerResponse.getArchivoOracle().getArchivo().getNombreArchivo() );
```

Do i need to configure something else to get the correct filename when downloading? my charset is set to UTF-8 i tried with ISO-8859-1 too without luck